# C# Unit Test using database data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, nunit

I am currently writing unit test using nunit. To do this i get data from the database and pass through the method that i want to test, then i compare database table data are same as the method return data. I have a doubt is this good to do unit test? Can someone explain this? I have tried moq test but it has some problem with my methods. sometimes findasync not work for return list in Moq test. then i giveup it  and turned to nunit test. I write unit test for entity framework.

```
[Test]
    public async Task GetFirmSectionListAsync_Count_AreEqual()
    {
        var fICount = _clientDbContext.FITypes.ToList().Count;
        var fIResult = await _firmService.GetFISListAsync(new CancellationToken(), Startup.ConnString);

        Assert.AreEqual(fICount, fIResult.Entities.Count);
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. Could you specify your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try to answer your question, I'll quote the various parts:

> To do this i get data from the database and pass through the method that i want to test, then i compare database table data are same as the method return data. I have a doubt is this good to do unit test? Can someone explain this?

Your way of unit testing is not really good practice. Let me explain. There are 2 things to consider here. Let me start with the first one.

First

Normally you would like to have a unit test in which the input and output are fixed, or at least independent of an external datasource like tables/rows/records in a database. So, in general it's better, and easier to create your data-set in memory, in your unit test.

Second

You need to be aware or *what* it is exactly what you want to test. In your case it seems ike you are testing the Entity Framework, which you might want to consider already tested.

> I have tried moq test but it has some problem with my methods. sometimes findasync not work for return list in Moq test. then i giveup it and turned to nunit test. I write unit test for entity framework.

So, I think it's better to focus on these problems. and: *"write unit test for entity framework"* seems overkill unless you are developping it.

---

So,  what would be a good thing to test?

Well you methods like `GetFirmSectionListAsync` perhaps. Maybe there is some internal logic going on, which you can test. But to do so, use a static dataset which covers all the logic scenario's. You don't twant your test/build to fail because somebody deleted some records.

Comment: Thank you for  your reply. I handle these things in my test methods. i added assert.ignore if dataset return null like this way:
"var firmInfo = _clientDbContext.FirmInfoes.AsEnumerable().LastOrDefault();
            if (firmInfo == null) { Assert.Ignore("There are no any records in the FirmInfo table"); } "

Comment: Yes, but handling those cases doesn't make it good practice. Try to think about my comments and remarks and decide what you want to do.